# Display 3 posts with different HTML markup using a loop

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, query-posts

I want to be able to display 3 posts from the same category on my index.php page, but due to the way my site's HTML/CSS is coded I'm having some difficulty understanding the correct way to go about doing this using a loop (as the code for the divs being used are not the same for all three sections, it's using different CSS styles to achieve a layered effect/look ).

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="first-story" class="story">
<div class="content">
<h3 class="story-heading">Headline 1</h3>
<ul>
   <li>Nullam sit amet scelerisque est. </li>   
   <li>Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis sed nisi nunc, faucibus rutrum mauris. </li>
   <li>Nullam iaculis lorem ut tortor ullamco per aliquet. Integer id leo non mauris pulvinar gravida vitae a enim. </li>
   <li>Nullam sit amet scelerisque est.</li>
</ul>   
    <a class="learnmore" href="#"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
<div class="edge"></div>
```

```
<div id="second-story" class="story">
<div class="content">
 <h3 class="story-heading">Headline 2</h3>
   <p>Paragraph text</p>
   <a class="learnmore" href="#"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="third-story" class="story">
<div class="edge"></div>
<div class="content">Headline 3</div>
        <ul>
           <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
        <a class="learnmore" href="#"><img src="img/button-learnmore.png"></a></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WordPress query object has an internal counter, `current_post`, which you can use to check the position of the post in the loop you are currently outputting, whether it's the main query `$wp_query` or a custom query you create via `WP_Query`. The important thing to remember about `current_post` is that it's **zero indexed**, the first post is 0, the second post is 1, etc..

Example, using the main query in a template:

```
while( have_posts() ):
    the_post();

    if( 0 == $wp_query->current_post ) {
        echo 'this is the first post';
        // markup for first post
    } elseif( 1 == $wp_query->current_post ) {
        echo 'this is the second post';
    } elseif( 2 == $wp_query->current_post ) {
        echo 'this is the third post';
    } else {
        echo 'this is > third post';
    }

endwhile;
```

If you create a new query via `WP_Query`, you do the same thing, except you reference the query object you created with your custom query:

```
$args = array(); // your custom query args
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $custom_query->have_posts() ):
    $custom_query->the_post();

    if( 0 == $custom_query->current_post ) {
        echo 'this is the first post';
    }
    // etc..

endwhile;
```